# Ruby on rails building association scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, scope

How can I list all the Games in the index page according to the number of lovers? thanks

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reverse_relationships, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => "game_id",    :class_name => "Relationship"
  has_many :lovers, :through => :reverse_relationships, :source => :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Game.all(:include => :lovers).sort{|a,b| b.lovers.size <=> a.lovers.size}
```

Comment: Sorry, "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"